# POP3 receive location is not able to connect to mail server

Tags: biztalk, pop3, receive-location

I've added a receive location in biztalk sever console and I'm getting the warning saying it's not connecting.

I've checked the connection outside biztalk and it's working. Based on that the problem must be with biztalk console definitions or properties and not with the mail server or the machine.

Is there some definition that enables outgoing ports for biztalk console or something similar that could fix the issue?

Testing the connection:

Connection succeed:

The username and password are correct:

Setup of the location:

Warning I get:

```
  POP3 
       The POP3 adapter could not establish a connection with the POP3 server. This could be due to the following reasons: 
1) The POP3 server host and port information is incorrect. 
2) The POP3 server is not running or is not reachable due to network issues. 
URL: POP3://mail.ABC.gv.ao#transaccoes.mercado@ABC.gv.ao Error: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

Comment: I don't think that telnet connection is successful to be honest. Have you tried using a regular e-mail client to test the connection?

Comment: @Ruud I think when you get a blank window the connection is successful. But what other e-mail client do you suggest? I was able to log in through the browser as can be seen in the 3rd screenshot.

Comment: I'd expect some response in the telnet window to be sure it's working. Also the webmail doesn't use POP3, so that's not saying anything either. The easiest way to test if it's enabled is to use any mail client (e.g. Windows Mail or Gmail) and add the account there. Just make sure you're using POP3 when doing so.

Comment: Have you tried to do the following procedure? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789740(v=exchg.80).aspx As far as I can tell, you should get a welcome message from the server.

Comment: Sorry, that's not a successful POP3 connection.  The server should at least respond with OK.  If you type "USER", what happens?

Comment: @Johns-305 If I type something the connection is lost without any message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if any component is inactive with the command:

```
Get-ServerComponentstate -Identity <Entity Name>
```

If it is, activate it with the command:

```
Set-ServerComponentState -Identity <Entity Name> -Component <Inactive Component Name> -Requester HealthAPI -State Active
```

Note: If you don't know the name of your entity you can get all entities in the server with the command:

```
Get-MailBox | FL Identity
```